# Как на python понять что была нажата кнопка на клавиатуре?

Tags: python

Мне нужно чтобы код начинал работать по нажатию кнопки например `num*` и заканчивал на `num/`, как такое можно сделать?

Я уже могу догадаться что `while done:` и `done = True` если нажата `*` и `False` если `/`, но как понять что была нажата то кнопка?

Answer (score 3):

```
In [3]: import msvcrt

In [4]: def foo():
   ...:     while True:
   ...:         print('Press any key')
   ...:         print(msvcrt.getch())
   ...:

In [5]: foo()
Press any key
b'H'
Press any key
b'f'
Press any key
b'w'
```

Answer (score 2):

Решил написать через tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
ret=True
def exit_root(event):
    while ret:
        print("----") # здесь писать код 
        root.update()
def g(event):
    global ret
    ret=False
    root.destroy()
root.withdraw()
root.bind("На какую кнопку надо нажать чтобы начать(кроме русских)", exit_root)
root.bind("На какую кнопку надо нажать чтобы выйти(кроме русских)", g)
root.mainloop()
```